# java Portuguese charset

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a problem with the charset on my program.
Using netbeans, when I run my program, on the output window `opções`shows as expected but using command prompt it shows like `opþ§es`.

On project properties, encoding is set to UTF-8 so I changed to windows-1252 (I believe that this is the portuguese charset) and now `opções` shows as `op├º├Áes`.

How can I fix this to `opções` shows as `opções`?

favolas

Comment: Nops. That did not solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change anything in your program. If it works correctly in NetBeans, then it runs correctly. You're seeing strange characters in the Windows command prompt because it doesn't handle non-ascii chars correctly. The problem is in the Windows command prompt, not in your program.

See [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)

Comment: Sweet. But to work as expected, charset must be set as windows-1252 and after typing chcp 65001 everything shows as it should

Comment: actually, the code may not be correct, it may just happen to work correctly depending on the platform character encoding.  hard to tell anything without seeing code.